# Is there a better way to combine arrays?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have two lists of information:

- Slots: this contains the time slots for the day
- Appointments: this contains the list of appointments for the day

I want to combine the list

The code i'm using works except if there are 2 appointments at the same time. Meaning if "14:00" exists twice in `slots` (which is a valid scenario) then they will both be filled by the last person to have a time at 14:00.

```
var slots = [
    {timeslot:"14:00",name:""},
    {timeslot:"14:00",name:""}, 
    {timeslot:"15:00",name:""},
    {timeslot:"16:00",name:""}
]

var appointments = [
    {timeslot:"14:00",name:"foo" }, 
    {timeslot:"14:00",name:"bar"},
    {timeslot:"15:00",name:"car"}
]

for (let slot of this.slots) {
  for (let appointment of appoinments) {
    if (slot.timeslot == appointment.timeslot) {
      slot.name = appointment.name
    }
  }
}
```

Desired output :

```
filtered list = [
    {timeslot:"14:00",name:"foo" }, 
    {timeslot:"14:00",name:"bar"},
    {timeslot:"15:00",name:"car"}, 
    {timeslot:"16:00",name:"empty"}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

```
const slots = [
  { timeslot: '14:00', name: '' },
  { timeslot: '14:00', name: '' },
  { timeslot: '15:00', name: '' },
  { timeslot: '15:00', name: '' },
  { timeslot: '16:00', name: '' }
];

const appointments = [
  { timeslot: '14:00', name: 'foo' },
  { timeslot: '14:00', name: 'bar' },
  { timeslot: '15:00', name: 'car' }
];

const combined = [];

slots.forEach(slot => {
  const matchingAppointmentIdx = appointments.findIndex((a) => a.timeslot === slot.timeslot);
  if (matchingAppointmentIdx >= 0) {
    combined.push(appointments[matchingAppointmentIdx]);
    appointments.splice(matchingAppointmentIdx, 1);

  } else {
    combined.push({ timeslot: slot.timeslot, name: 'empty' });
  }
});
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-7-bootstrap-4-4ip8c when you add another time slots, so 3 of the same time you get duplication issues.

Answer (score 0):

More simple:

```
const slots = [
  { timeslot: '14:00', name: '' },
  { timeslot: '15:00', name: '' }, 
  { timeslot: '16:00', name: '' }
];

const appointments = [
  { timeslot: '14:00', name: 'foo' },
  { timeslot: '14:00', name: 'bar' }, 
  { timeslot: '15:00', name: 'car' }
];

const combined = slots.map(slot => {
  const found = appointments.find(appointment => appointment.timeslot === slot.timeslot);
    return {
      timeslot: slot.timeslot,
      name: found ? found.name : 'empty'
    }
  });


console.log(JSON.stringify(combined, null, 4));
```